# Why is there a really bright patch on my laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display

I opened up my laptop, and there was there this super bright patch on my screen. I was using it this morning with no problem, so I'm not sure what happened. The laptop was sitting in the sun(closed) for a while, but not too long.
Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your LCD panel is physically damaged. This kind of damage is usually caused by putting pressure on the lid.

LCDs are replaceable. They aren't cheap, but it looks like a 1366x768 panel - it will be at the cheaper end of spectrum. I'm just eyeballing it though, so if you're going to replace it yourself make sure to check its native resolution before replacement and make sure the new one is compatible.

Comment: Something laying between the base and the cover when you close the lid can be enough. I’ve seen similar damage done by a quarter coin. If the laptop has a small joystick button between the keys then some weight on top of the closed laptop may push the LCD hard enough against that knob to cause this. Actually this could be the case here from the look of it. Get the LCD replaced by the manufacturer (even if not covered under warranty) or a reputable repair shop to make sure it is done right. Get a quote first. It isn’t always worth it on older laptops.

Comment: Thanks for that. I opened it up today, and it has just disappeared! no sign of it now. not sure how that happened, but I'm not complaining...